# DataSet no muestra datos en crystalreport c#

Tags: c#, crystal-reports, dataset

Vengo con un pequeño problema que tal vez a algunos se le presento y lo pudo resolver.

Tengo mi método load en donde asigno el dataset a mi reporte como se ve en el código.

```
private void Frm_Impresion_Presupuesto_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        String connstring = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Trabajo"].ToString();
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connstring))
        {
            try
            {
                String filePath = @"D:\Reporte\Reporte_Presupuesto.rpt";
                //Cargar el Reporte
                rd.Load(filePath);
                //Asignarle al Reporte el DataSet                    
                rd.SetDataSource(PresupuestoCod(SecPre));
                //Asignarle al CrystalReportViewer el ReportDocument 
                crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = rd;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("ERROR : " + ex.Message, "ERROR!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
        }
    }
```

Posteriormente ejecuta este código en donde manda a llamar a una función `fn_Find_Presupuesto_Impresion` y le envió un parámetro que devuelve un resultado en base a una coincidencia.

```
    public static DataSetImpresionPresupuesto PresupuestoCod(String CODPRE)
 {
            DataSetImpresionPresupuesto ds = new DataSetImpresionPresupuesto();
            using (SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Trabajo"].ToString()))
            {
                string query = "SELECT * FROM fn_Find_Presupuesto_Impresion(@CODPRE)";
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, cnn);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("CODPRE", CODPRE);
                Console.WriteLine(CODPRE);
                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                da.Fill(ds, "SELECT * FROM fn_Find_Presupuesto_Impresion(@CODPRE)");
                return ds;
            }
        }
```

Ahora verificando con un breakpoint se llena el dataset como la imagen , me arroja que devuelve un resultado en base a la linea de depuración, pero sin embargo no se visualiza nada en el reporte.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Que podría estar realizando de manera equivocada para no llenar los datos en el reporte.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Despues de varios dias, logre encontrar la solucion y la pongo para cualquier persona

```
private void Frm_Impresion_Presupuesto_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string connstring = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Trabajo"].ToString();
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connstring))
        {
            try
            {
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                ReportDocument rd = new ReportDocument();
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("fn_Find_Presupuesto_Impresion", conn)
                {
                    CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
                };
                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@CODPRE", SecPre));
                da.Fill(ds, "fn_Find_Presupuesto_Impresion");
                if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count == 0)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("ERROR : NO HAY DATOS", "ERROR!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                    return;
                }
                //Cargar el Reporte
                rd.Load(Application.StartupPath.ToString()+ "\\frm\\Reporte_Presupuesto.rpt");
                //Asignarle al Reporte el DataSet                    
                rd.SetDataSource(ds);
                //Asignarle al CrystalReportViewer el ReportDocument 
                crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = rd;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("ERROR : " + ex.Message, "ERROR!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
        }
    }
```